# How to deactivate a UI element in an add-on?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

In an add-on I would like to have a property adjustable via its UI element, but when I have a second elements enabled I want my first element to be disabled : only show the information without being editable. It there a way to make a UI element read-only ? (grayed out / disabled / visible but un-editable).

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
col = layout.column()
col.enabled = False
# Use col.prop, col.operator, etc. Everything you add to this column will be faded
```

`col.active` is also possible, it will grey out the column but the props will still be editable (this is probably not something you want)

Comment: Actually the attribute i think I was looking for is enabled so the solution is more like col.enabled = False. Also if want only one property to be enabled/disabled I need to put just that property inside of a col/box/row UI element and then hide the col/box/row.

Comment: What about a specific item in a row? so maybe there is a randomize checkbox beside a color well. The box disabled the well. Seems only if it's on a separate row or hide it? but I want to see the randomized color in the well.

Comment: I thought this was a toggle at first (i.e. set `enabled` back to `True` after calling `prop()`), but you actually disable everything in the layout component or nothing at all. I had to create an extra `row()` to control just a single component.