# Mesh / object mode with Pie menu?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

The following command in edit or object mode is the same to create a new mesh cube:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add
```

I structured my pie this way but nothing happens - only when I am in edit mode.
I assume because mesh.primitive_cube_add is a mesh object? But it is the same readout in the console, when in object mode I press shift A and select the cube.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

class NewPie(Menu):
    bl_label = "Select Mode"
    bl_idname = "mypie"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NewPie)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Mesh")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "E", "PRESS", shift=True, ctrl=True).properties.name="mypie"

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NewPie)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="NewPie")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the shortcut to the Object Mode shortcuts so it would be captured when you are in object mode, so the register function would be like this :

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NewPie)
    #Add shortcuts
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    #Edit Mode    
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Mesh")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "E", "PRESS",shift=True, ctrl=True).properties.name="mypie"
    #Object Mode
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Object Mode")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "E", "PRESS", shift=True, ctrl=True).properties.name="mypie"
```

Comment: Aha - I was not aware of that Mesh is in deed referring to the edit mode. I understood it as the mesh area in the keymaps for sorting purpose in the preferences UI.

Comment: I just want some clarification here: the hotkey is determined by the section of the keymap it's in, not the viewport context? I was under the impression blender is based almost entirely on context. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the term.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's a little different. How you call `keymaps.new` will determine which context will trigger the menu. Currently you add the shortcut to Mesh, which is `EDIT_MODE`, therefore the menu only appears when you are in edit mode.

Instead of adding it to `Mesh` and `Object Mode` separately you might consider adding it the generic `3D View` keymappings, this will then trigger the menu whenever the mouse is in 3d view and you press the key-combo.

```
km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW')
```

Then inside your Menu layout you add logic which determines what kind of things to show depending on the mode of the Object.

---

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu


class NewPie(Menu):
    bl_label = "Select Mode"
    bl_idname = 'kwanza'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

        # if context.mode == 'OBJECT':
        #     something with object mode
        # else:
        #     something with edit mode 

addon_keymaps = []


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NewPie)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW')
    keymaps = km.keymap_items

    new_shortcut = keymaps.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "SEMI_COLON", "PRESS", shift=True)
    new_shortcut.properties.name = 'kwanza'
    addon_keymaps.append((km, new_shortcut))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NewPie)

    for km, shortcut in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(shortcut)
    addon_keymaps.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

A small note about the code you pasted in your Question.

The last line should be `bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="mypie")`. 
When you don't add a `bl_idname` to the Menu definition then you can call operators directly using the *class name*, otherwise if `bl_idname` is specified then you must use that instead.

---

A useful way to get a handle on how keymaps work is by setting them manually first, then using the keymap export feature to generate a .py file, and in this file do a search for your *operator name* or *menu name*

When I added kwanza to `3D View (Global)` it added this to the keymaps export

```
# Map 3D View
km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)

... (snipped)


kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', 'SEMI_COLON', 'PRESS', shift=True)
kmi_props_setattr(kmi.properties, 'name', 'kwanza')
```

Comment: Thank you for all the extra information - trying to understand the mode switch you talk about. I was curious already about how to define commands based on the mode you are in.

Comment: have a look at `space_view3d.py` lines like `if context.mode != 'OBJECT': `

Comment: I see it makes a function available if the mode is right or shades it inactive if the mode is wrong. I think I need to write the code for drawing the buttons with a condition of what mode the user is in. Let me try to figure this out - but might fail hahahaha.

Comment: The inactive shading is done explicitely:  see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41387/how-to-deactivate-a-ui-element-in-an-add-on

Comment: or through an if context mode is edit mesh like in the official pie menu as I just learned

Comment: sometimes the language needed to convey these concepts is much less transparent than the eventual code you end up reading / writing.

Comment: yes this is very true - what confuses me on top is also all the different ways how to do it.